# Type or namespace name 'Description' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

Im currently working on a MR application for UWP. I'm building the application in unity3d (tested in 5.5.2 and 2017.1.2) and everything works fine when i press play within unity, no compile errors what so ever... But when I go to build the application i get errors `Assets\Script\DMEWebRequest.cs(35,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DescriptionAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` and `Assets\Script\DMEWebRequest.cs(35,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Description' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

To my knowledge the DescriptionAttribute is a part of `System.ComponentModel`

Code snippets from my C# script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;


//Makes a dropdown menu in the inspector
public enum EGU {
    [Description("")] None,
    [Description("ºC")] DegreesCelcius,
    [Description("kW")] KiloWatts,
    [Description("kW/h")] KiloWattsPerHour,
    [Description("MW")] MegaWatts,
    [Description("MW/h")] MegaWattsPerHour,
    [Description("M³")] CubicMeters,
    [Description("M³/h")] CubicMetersPerHour,
    [Description("%")] Procentage,
    [Description("º")] Degrees,
    [Description("l/s")] LiterPerSecond,
    [Description("cm")] CentiMeters,
    [Description("m")] Meters,
    [Description("mg/l")] MiliGramPerLiter,
    [Description("g/l")] GramPerLiter
    }
```

Hope someone can help me figure out what directive or reference I'm missing.

/T

Comment: It presents in [`System.ComponentModel` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and you have already added it.

Comment: How did you added reference of `ComponentModel`?

Comment: Didn't do anything else then typing it out... But as @Programmer said in the answer it wont work with UWP :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code should work fine when building for PC, Mac & and Linux Standalone. It should not work when you switch the platform to Universal Windows Platform because `System.ComponentModel.Description` uses `DescriptionAttribute` which is not supported on UWP. UWP removed support for many .NET API. That's one thing you should bear in mind when making UWP app.

Comment: Ohh okay, thanks alot now it makes sence :) Would you know another way I could go about making a Public Enum with use of special chars(%, º, ³ etc.) other then doing a switch of the selected enum.

Comment: If I knew a way to get around this I would have added that to the answer. I don't really know. Maybe re-implementing this with the mono [source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CompMod/System/ComponentModel/DescriptionAttribute@cs/1/DescriptionAttribute@cs) may work. I am not sure but give that a try. Make sure to wrap that code around [`UNITY_WSA`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) macro so that it will only be used when you switch to UWP.

Comment: I'll give it a try, once again thanks for the answer. Been trying to wrap my mind around this for a few days :)

Comment: Np. Give it a try. If it works, I will edit that into my answer.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work. Ended with making a switch that converts the enum value to a string. :/

Comment: To be honest I didn't write it down. I was a bit in a hurry to complete the application for a showcase that's going down in 3 hours. I'll try to see if I can come up with a better solution, after this showcase.

Answer (score 0):

It works with IL2CPP as scripting backend. If you need the deprecated .NET scripting backend from Unity 2018 LTS (removed in 2019) you can try to add DescriptionAttribute.cs from Mono or decompiled code as @Programmer suggested. It might work in some situation but in my case I ran into more errors.

Finally I gave up when I tried to make ARSubsystem package compiling for UWP (.NET) which was needed in iOS/Android builds of the same project. Instead I manipulated package manifest to exclude / include the packages depending on the platform. There are a couple of ways to accomplish that like [InitializeOnLoad attribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/InitializeOnLoadAttribute.html) or [IPreprocessBuildWithReport](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.IPreprocessBuildWithReport.html) interface.